# How to get numbers of the rows with specific data?

Tags: r

I have got data.frame

```
          COL1         COL2 
1          X            X
2          X            X
3          X            Y
4          X            X
5          Z            X
```

If column has no X I need to get the number of appropriate row (3 and 5 in this case). I tried to use 'sapply' to check data through "!=", but I think I need something else.

Comment: X in any of the columns?

Comment: X could be anywhere. I need to know where X is not.

Comment: You don't need `sapply`, just: `which(!!rowSums(df != "X"))` or `which(df != "X", arr.ind = TRUE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using `which` that will work on any number of columns:

```
# example data
df <- data.frame(
    col1 = c("X", "X", "X", "X", "Z"),
    col2 = c("X", "X", "Z", "X", "X"),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

# how to get rows without X
unique(sapply(df, function(x) which(x != "X")))
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
library(dplyr)
filter(df, (COL1!="X" & COL2!="X"))
```

Comment: What if I have 100 columns?

Comment: @Jens I kindly suggest that you update your question accordingly and ask for solutions that will work with an arbitrary number of columns and not just two as in your sample dataset. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You were close, your idea of using `sapply` with primitive function `!=` is basically correct.

The following returns a logical matrix.

```
sapply(dat, `!=`, "X")
#      COL1  COL2
#[1,] FALSE FALSE
#[2,] FALSE FALSE
#[3,] FALSE  TRUE
#[4,] FALSE FALSE
#[5,]  TRUE FALSE
```

If you need row numbers, wrap that in `which`, with argument `arr.ind` set to `TRUE`.

```
which(sapply(dat, `!=`, "X"), arr.ind = TRUE)
#     row col
#[1,]   5   1
#[2,]   3   2
```

**Edit.**

Several solutions were posted, here are comparison tests.
Since the OP says that there could be datasets with 100 columns, I have tested with two different datasets, the posted in the question and a larger one.

Function `RuiJaap` is `Rui` with the suggestion in Jaap's comment.

```
Rui <- function(DF, value = "X")
  which(sapply(DF, `!=`, value), arr.ind = TRUE)

DanY <- function(DF, value = "X")
  unique(sapply(DF, function(x) which(x != value)))

Jaap <- function(DF, value = "X")
  which(!!rowSums(DF != value))

RuiJaap <- function(DF, value = "X")
  which(dat != "X", arr.ind = TRUE)

library(ggplot2)
library(microbenchmark)

mb1 <- microbenchmark(Rui = Rui(dat),
                      RuiJaap = RuiJaap(dat),
                      Jaap = Jaap(dat),
                      DanY = DanY(dat),
                      times = 1e3)

mb2 <- microbenchmark(Rui = Rui(dat2),
                      RuiJaap = RuiJaap(dat2),
                      Jaap = Jaap(dat2),
                      DanY = DanY(dat2),
                      times = 1e2)

autoplot(mb1)
autoplot(mb2)
```

For small datasets `DanY` is faster but for larger ones, `RuiJaap` is the fastest.

**Data.**

```
dat <- read.table(text = "
          COL1         COL2 
1          X            X
2          X            X
3          X            Y
4          X            X
5          Z            X                  
", header = TRUE)


set.seed(1)
dat2 <- matrix("X", nrow = 20, ncol = 100)
dat2[sample(2000, 100)] <- "Y"
dat2 <- as.data.frame(dat2)
```

Comment: See also [my comment under the Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52705786/how-to-get-numbers-of-the-rows-with-specific-data#comment92338211_52705786), `sapply` isn't needed; just `which(df != "X", arr.ind = TRUE)` works too.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `tidyverse` solution that can work on an arbitrary number of columns

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
 col1 = c("X", "X", "X", "X", "Z"),
 col2 = c("X", "X", "Z", "X", "X"),
 col3 = c("X", "X", "Z", "Z", "X"),
)

filter_all(df, any_vars(. != "X"))
```

Which returns:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
 col1  col2  col3
  <chr> <chr> <chr>
  1     X     Z     Z
  2     X     X     Z
  3     Z     X     X
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a base R solution that will work for any number of columns -

`which(rowSums(df == "X") != ncol(df))`